# Empty Events from Flume HTTPSource

Tags: flume, flume-ng

I'm trying to setup a very simple workflow in Flume that does this:

JSON Data -> HTTPSource -> Memory Channel -> Logger

I am attempting to POST this data:

> [ { "string" : "this is a test post" }]

But here is what I get in the logger:

> 18/08/09 17:45:30 INFO sink.LoggerSink: Event: { headers:{} body: }

I can tell that the HTTPSource is receiving the data because if I send an invalid JSON message, I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but
>   was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3

Here is my flume config:

```
# Agent ============================================================================
booking.sources = httpsource
booking.channels = channel
booking.sinks = hdfssink

# Source ============================================================================
booking.sources.httpsource.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
booking.sources.httpsource.port = 8090
booking.sources.httpsource.bind = localhost


# Channel ============================================================================
booking.channels.channel.type = memory
booking.channels.channel.capacity = 50000
booking.channels.channel.transactionCapacity = 5000

booking.sources.httpsource.channels = channel
booking.sinks.hdfssink.channel = channel


# Sink ============================================================================
booking.sinks.hdfssink.type = logger
```

I'm running it with the following command:

```
flume-ng agent --conf conf --conf-file conf/test.conf --name booking -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

And here is the command that I'm using to post the JSON data:

```
curl --verbose --header "Content-Type: application/json" -k -d "@test.txt" -X POST http://localhost:8091
```

Does anyone have any idea where the data may be going? Or maybe some additional steps to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This was just me not reading enough of the documentation. The format of the json needed for JSONHandler is [{ headers:{}, body: ""}] and my test didn't conform to that.

Here is the documentation that helped: http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#jsonhandler